# Android 4.2 - DatePicker crashes when minDate is set and selected date before minDate

Tags: android, datepicker

In 4.2 JB, my app that uses the DatePicker crashes.
This happens only when a minDate is set (setMinDate). When I scroll to a date before the minDate, the app crashes.

The crash occurs both on my Samsung Galaxy Nexus and on the emulator with Android 4.2.
This bug doesn't occur using the emulator with Android 4.1.

I build the app against 4.2 (API 17).

Anybody else with this issue or am I the only one?

I already created a bug report. You can see the crash log there.
[Goolge bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=41025)

UPDATE: Seems like they fixed this bug in 4.2.1

Comment: You can't not set the minDate to current date try adding 1000ms to current date

Comment: I already tried setting it a few days/months back. Why shouldn't I be able to set it to the past? This worked before 4.2!

Comment: are you trying something  like this setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 5000*60)

Comment: I get the time from a Calendar object (minDate) and call it like this:
datePicker.setMinDate(minDate.getTimeInMillis());

Comment: why are you not setting the minDate like this datePicker.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - yourTimeInMiliSecons)

Comment: Why should this make any difference? I calculated the desired minDate before and as long as it is a Calendar with a valid date set I don't see any problems with it. I repeat myself: this worked before 4.2!

Comment: Found the solution, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39398562/6520530