# DatePicker crashes when select date beyond min or max date. Android 5.1

Tags: android, datepicker

I have this code:

```
public void onDateSet( DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth )
{
    Log.v( "DateRangePicker", "Date CHANGED" );
}

...

Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
calender.setTime( new Date() );
DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog( 
        getActivity(), 
        this,
        calender.get( Calendar.YEAR ), calender.get( Calendar.MONTH ),
        calender.get( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH ) );

DatePicker picker = dialog.getDatePicker();
picker.setMaxDate( System.currentTimeMillis() );
dialog.show();
```

I saw a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13746035/android-4-2-datepicker-crashes-when-mindate-is-set-and-selected-date-before-mi) helping this kind of problem for android 4.2, it seems to be solved on further versions. But not in my case.

[image]

When I scroll the month to (september) it gives the crash below. I don't know for sure but, I think september should not be even there.

```
  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.hizzo.counter, PID: 23871
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Time not between Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 AMT 1900 and Wed Aug 26 11:49:46 AMT 2015
        at android.widget.CalendarViewLegacyDelegate.goTo(CalendarViewLegacyDelegate.java:775)
        at android.widget.CalendarViewLegacyDelegate.setDate(CalendarViewLegacyDelegate.java:592)
        at android.widget.CalendarView.setDate(CalendarView.java:495)
        at android.widget.DatePicker$DatePickerSpinnerDelegate.updateCalendarView(DatePicker.java:1069)
        at android.widget.DatePicker$DatePickerSpinnerDelegate.access$800(DatePicker.java:536)
        at android.widget.DatePicker$DatePickerSpinnerDelegate$1.onValueChange(DatePicker.java:642)
        at android.widget.NumberPicker.notifyChange(NumberPicker.java:1888)
        at android.widget.NumberPicker.setValueInternal(NumberPicker.java:1674)
        at android.widget.NumberPicker.scrollBy(NumberPicker.java:1137)
        at android.widget.NumberPicker.computeScroll(NumberPicker.java:1091)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14172)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14207)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3391)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3370)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14145)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14207)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3391)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3370)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14145)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14207)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3391)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3370)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14145)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14207)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3391)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3370)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14145)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14207)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3391)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3370)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14145)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14207)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3391)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3370)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14145)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14207)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3391)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3370)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14145)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14207)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3391)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3370)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14145)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14207)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3391)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3370)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14145)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14207)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:273)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:279)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:318)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2560)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2382)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2012)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1084)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5990)
        at android.view.Choreographer$Call
```

Comment: what's the value of targetDate

Comment: I remove that line, same problem, and now I just set to `new Date()`. It seems to be irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

DatePicker needs to be inited to be able to set min or max date. I just change `dialog.show()` before it. :\

```
Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
calender.setTime( new Date() );
DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog( 
        getActivity(), 
        this,
        calender.get( Calendar.YEAR ), calender.get( Calendar.MONTH ),
        calender.get( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH ) );
dialog.show();

DatePicker picker = dialog.getDatePicker();
picker.setMaxDate( System.currentTimeMillis() );
```

Answer (score 0):

This must be an bug within the `DatePicker` class itself, I got it to work by setting the `minDate` first, and THEN the `maxDate` (in that order). If I swap the order or omit one of the method calls I get that weird exception.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem for some of the android versions, the solution was to set MaxDate as follows:

```
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal1.set(Calendar.YEAR, maxYear);
cal1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
cal1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
cal1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
cal1.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,999);
datePicker.setMaxDate(cal1.getTimeInMillis());
```

The point was to set max date with maximum millisecond representing the given date/day(at the end of the day). It would be the opposite for setting minDate (at the begining of the day)